Imprimir matriz secundaria
Estoy intentando hacer que se imprima la diagonal secundaria de una matriz n*n usando ** seria algo asi como:
03 02 **    
03 ** 01
** 02 01

Lo he logrado mas o menos pero lo he hecho al revés y no entiendo mucho como cambiarlo. Sé que mi problema esta en algún for pero no se que cambiar exactamente
este es mi codigo
    package Practica;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
   
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño de la matriz (n): ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(input);

        
        int[][] matriz = new int[n][n];

     
        int contador = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                matriz[i][j] = contador++;
            }
        }

       
        StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder();

    
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (j == n - i - 1) {
                    resultado.append("** ");
                } else {
                    resultado.append(String.format("%02d ", matriz[i][j]));
                }
            }
            resultado.append("\n");
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, resultado.toString());
    }
}


Explica que es una matriz secundaria

Mi error, no me explique bien. Seria una diagonal que divide una matriz

Para obtener la siguiente matriz:
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3

Necesitas inicializarla correctamente
int contador = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
       //matriz[i][j] = contador++; // Esto esta mal, genera una matriz del 1 al 9
        matriz[i][j] = j + 1; //Esto si genera filas del 1 al 3
    }
}

Luego tú quieres imprimir invirtiendo las columnas, para esto haces un for de derecha a izquierda (esto lo tienes perfecto). Tu problema está en la condifición del if
Veamos cómo queda la matriz con las posiciones ( i , j )
0,2  0,1  0,0
1,2  1,1  1,0
2,2  2,1  2,0

Si te fijas veras que en la diagonal secundaria i == j siempre, por lo que esa debe ser tu condición
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (j == i)
        {
            resultado.append("** ");
        }
        else
        {
            resultado.append(String.format("%02d ", matriz[i][j]));
        }
    }
    resultado.append("\n");
}

